# Training a Neural-network with a single output which has a wide range

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a data-set where the single output which I want to predict varies in the range of 10^10 to 10^18. 
What activation function should I use in the output layer and how should I normalise the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just predict log10(output) - 14, this will make the output range (-4, 4). final activation function can be linear (no activation).

The activations of the neurons in the network are usually normalized to have the mean 0 and variance 1. Hence it is desired that the output follows similar distribution. Forcing the network to predict range (10^10, 10^18) is still possible, but it makes the training slower (eg the network would need to learn to multiply initial output by 10^14).

Comment: Thanks. Will try this.

Comment: What kind of "Metric" should I use for this? Things like "accuracy" won't work because the output-layer has a single entry.

Comment: The metric should ideally measure something you care about. In the log space the mean squared error is already quite a good metric - it measures the average log(prediction/actual)^2 value. You can spend some time to actually understand why this is important. You can set up some simple baselines - like for example a classifier that predicts always 0, or the mean output value. The goal is to be better than these. The metric and the objective function should be ideally as close to your goal as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize the data by log.
Or 10^n is also good.
I think this is enough.

Comment: How will the activation function change then?

Comment: You can use lambda x:tf.math.pow(10,x) as an activation function, but I suggest to log the data.

Comment: Pow will not work well with standard squared loss function. With pow I suggest to use(1 - prediction / actual)**2 as a loss.